# Wrong data displayed on many onchange

Tags: javascript, jquery, onchange

I'm having trouble having code onchange inside onchange event.

some code works and some dont work due to that.

```
<script>
    $(document).on('change', '.sellkop', function() { // this is radio button
        if ($("#rs").is(':checked')) {
                 $("#text_container").after(price_option());
            };
        if ($("#rk").is(':checked')) {
               $("#price_container").remove();
               $("#licensenumber_c").css({"display": 'none'
           });
         };
    });

 $('#category_group').on('change', function() { // this is select options

    if ($(this).val() == 101) {
              $("#underKategory").css({"display": 'none'});
              $("#modelcontainer").remove();
              $(".toolimage").css({ "display": 'block'});

        $('.sellkop').on('change', function() { // this is radio button
            if ($("#rs").is(':checked')) {
                $("#licensenumber_c").css({"display": 'block'});
                $(".toolimage").css({"display": 'block' });
            } else {
                $(".toolimage").css({"display": 'none'});
            }
        });
    } else {
               $(".bilar").remove();
              $(".toolimage").css({ "display": 'none'});
    }
    if ($(this).val() == 102) {
                $(".houses_container").remove();
                $(".toolimage").css({"display": 'none'});
                $("#underKategory").css({"display": 'inline-block'});
                $("#modelcontainer").remove();
    }

    ///............many other values continue
 });
</script>
```

I know there is better way to manage this code and simplify it but i have no idea how ?

EDIT:

**What i want is :**  if i select an option , then get the values to that option, then under this category option there is radio buttons , so every check button i need to get some data displayed or removed

here is a [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4s5rwce2/7/) there looks my problem .

**what happens:** 
if i select category-->check buy -->then select others . i dont get same result as if i select directly cars ---> buy

Comment: updated your code readability... ;)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Why is there a need to nest the event handlers? Is one event dependent on another taking place?

Comment: because , if select an option , then get values to that , then under this category option there is radio buttons , then every check button i need to get some data displayed or removed.

Answer (score -1):

try following script:
            function saljkop(){
            var x = "\
                     Sell \
                    buy\
                    ";
            return x ;
            }
            function price_option(){
            var x = '\
                    \
                    \
                 Fix \
               \
                     offer \
                    \
            ';
            return x ;
            }
            function cars(){
                    var x = '\
            ';
                return x
            }

```
        $("#categories").after(saljkop());

        $(document).on('change', '.sellkop', function() { // this is radio button
                if ($("#rs").is(':checked')) {
                     $("#price_container").remove();
                         $("#text_container").after(price_option());

                    };
                if ($("#rk").is(':checked')) {

                       $("#price_container").remove();
                       $("#licensenumber_c").css({"display": 'none'
                   });
                 };
            });

         $('#category_group').on('change', function() { // this is select options

            if ($(this).val() == 101) {
                      $("#sellbuy").after(cars())  ;
                 $("#price_container").remove();
                      $("#text_container").after(price_option());
                      $("#underKategory").css({"display": 'none'});
                      $(".toolimage").css({ "display": 'block'});


            } else {
                       $(".cars").remove();
                      $(".toolimage").css({ "display": 'none'});
            }
            if ($(this).val() == 102) {
                         $("#price_container").remove();
                         $("#text_container").after(price_option());
                        $(".toolimage").css({"display": 'none'});
                        $("#underKategory").css({"display": 'inline-block'});
            }

            ///............many other values continue
         });
```

Comment: I dont know what have you changed , have you checked my new fiddle now?. your script is not working also. Look. select category-->check buy -->then select others . i dont get same result as i want if if i select directly cars ---> buy.

Comment: replace your code by my code after this line  $("#categories").after(saljkop());

Comment: Have tryed it in the fiddle all. But same problem as i told in my comment.